# pyqt4: Making Qtableview reflect the changes after calling QStandardItem.setData

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

I'm trying to build a gui using pyqt4 and am having trouble updating fields on a `Qtableview`
Here's my code:

```
table=QTableView(myqMainWindow)
model=QStandardItemModel(0,1,table)
item1= QStandardItem("123")
model.setItem(0,0,item1)
table.setModel(model) 
item1.setData("321")
```

Now the problem I'm facing is that the table still shows "123" at the first column. What is it that I'm missing to get the table reflect the change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a closer look at `setData` [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditem.html#setData).

`setData` take two arguments : **data** and **role**. Unless you want to define a custom role you must specify one. In your case, you should use `DisplayRole`

```
item1.setData("321", QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
```

Alternatively, you could use `setText`.

```
item1.setText("321")
```